# How to Secure Credentials for App Making REST Calls

Tags: node.js, rest, security

I have a nodejs app that makes REST calls for the user. The REST calls require basic authentication, and the user does not have to provide this information since the app will take care of making the call for the user.

What are the best practices for securing those api credentials in a case like this? I definitely do not want the credentials to be plaintext in the source. I also think I should stay away from storing the credentials in environment variables. Since the app itself does not authenticate the credentials, I do not believe I should be using oauth or tokens.

It also seems like a catch-22 if I want to store the credentials in a database or something similar because I would then have to secure the credentials for those api calls as well.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere you store the credentials, you have to think about what can access it. Not storing them in source is a good idea, because credentials can be read by developers and whoever has access to source control.

Environment variables can be used for this, so could a configuration file. The question remains with environment variables, how do those variables get set? Are you running `export` manually somewhere? If not, there's likely still a script or configuration file that populates it. Who can see those files?

It's not unusual for programs running on unix systems to run under their own username with limited access, and any secret files to have file mode `600`. (e.g. Only the current user can see it).

If you are running on something like AWS or a competitor, these systems also have secret management services, but this may or may not be overkill depending on your needs.

Comment: If I manually populate the environment file, is that secure enough of a process that I would not have to worry about additional security? Would it be more secure if I were to make an additional file that holds the credentials or is it on the same level? Would it be any different if I exported the variables directly using 'exports'?

Comment: Files are just files. Who has access to the files is what you should be asking.